# "Along" versus "together" or "alongside"

Tags: word-choice

Can I say this sentence, where *along* means *together*?

> They were walking along.

Should I instead say *They were walking together* or *They were walking alongside*?

Answer (score 1):

Your first two can be used as is, but would normally be used as a fragment of a longer sentence.

Your third example is incomplete, would only normally be used with "each other" or "the river" tacked on the end. (And often much more.)

Comment: Could you give me some examples with the first 2 sentences in a longer sentence, like you said?